# What calendar control can I use for mobile web site?

Tags: asp.net, browser, mobile, calendar

I'm developing a web site in ASP.NET/C# that is targeted at mobile users.

What calendar control do you recommend, that will work on Nokia, Safari, Opera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that [most browsers support Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255048/which-mobile-browsers-support-javascript-and-ajax), so I'm going to go with a nice Ajax control from [Telerik](http://telerik.com).

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for mobile UI, take a look at [Mobiscroll Calendar Control](http://mobiscroll.com/component/calendar).

The UX was specifically created for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mobile:Calendar control in the System.Web.UI.MobileControls namespace if you are using ASP .Net Mobile WebForms.  [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.mobilecontrols.calendar%28VS.80%29.aspx).  You will need to test it on the devices/OSes you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is using a textbox with some validation :-)