# Which mobile browsers support javascript (and Ajax)?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, browser, mobile

For the web site I'm building (targeted at mobile users) I'm thinking of using some Ajax controls.  I'd like to know which mobile browsers do and don't support Javascript and Ajax, so I can know whether I've at least covered the majority of my target market (i.e. iPhone, Droid, Nokia, Opera).  If not, I'll have to find an alternative way of presenting my forms...

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've found [ppk's list on quirksmode](http://quirksmode.org/m/table.html) very helpful. It's not a 100% complete resource, but should cover most major browsers.

Comment: +1 for the Quirksmode link (I included it in my answer too), it's a great resource.

Answer (score 4):

Given "recent" phones, you'l find the answer is "most of them".

Along with the sites already listed, consider [Device Atlas](http://deviceatlas.com/).

Comment: +1 for Device Atlas but -1 for "Script Support". I've never seen anything more comprehensive. But "supported" for them means "enabled by default". Most (possibly all) BlackBerry devices are listed as not having Script Support, when in fact it disabled by default and can be enabled by the user (not that the majority of users know how to do it). That's always bothered me. But for native screen resolution and user agent info, though, it's an amazing resource!

Comment: @Andrew what are you talking about? What is this "script support" you're talking about? I have no idea what your comment means.

Comment: The OP asked, "which mobile browsers do and don't support Javascript". Device Atlas lists "Script Support", but that is either misleading or inaccurate for many devices, such as BB, that **do** support JavaScript but are shipped with it disabled by default. It is a really great resource, but doesn't answer OP's question.

Comment: @Andrew: Ah, thanks for clarifying. Yes, perhaps not such a great resource then.

Comment: Note that DeviceAtlas now has very granular for JavaScript and HTML5 properties. There are now about 20 distinct JavaScript properties covering features such as support for XHR, console.log() and HTML5-related features such as SVG, indexeddb and web sockets. 

As an example, here is the page for the Samsung Galaxy S2 (check the JavaScipt and HTML5 section): http://deviceatlas.com/node/2410065

Answer (score 2):

This may be slightly OT, but it's worth noting here, w.r.t. direct javascript support, that there's two types of mobile "browsers" - there are browsers with JS interpreters in them (like Opera **Mobile**, iPhone Safari, Droid) and then there are "thin clients" (like Opera **Mini**, Bolt, Skyfire etc.).

Thin clients support scripting, but do so in a different way. They have no JS engine on the phone - the JS is executed on the server and the result of that is then sent to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

The default browsers included in Android, iOS Safari (iPhone) and Nokia all support JavaScript and Ajax.  As does Opera Mini.  Be aware, though, that it can be disabled (at least, in Opera Mini and Safari).

Quirksmode has [compatibility tables](http://quirksmode.org/m/table.html) for mobile browsers.  When in doubt, use feature detection and try and leave a fallback for when JavaScript is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) to find the capabilities of the mobile devices serverside and present a page accordingly.